# Looking for iOS VoiceOver accessibility guidelines: when I tap on text, how much should it speak?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm looking for any specific guidelines (from Apple or elsewhere - not opinions) on how much text I should make VoiceOver read when I tap on some text in the app I'm developing.

When I tap on a header, should it read only the header, or should it also read the section below that header? When I tap on a paragraph, should it read the header and then the entire section that contains this paragraph? In what situations should the spoken text provide more or different information than is actually displayed by the app?

(I'm not asking what it *does*, I'm asking what it *should do*, because as a developer I can set an item's `accessibilityLabel` to as much or as little text as I want.)

I don't see anything relevant in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5.

Answer (score 2):

Your link seems clear enough, especially the section on [Supply Accurate and Helpful Attribute Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW4) which includes, among other details, the following:

> A good way to determine what a label should convey is to think about what a sighted user infers about your application just by looking at it. If you’ve designed a good user interface, sighted users should know what a control or view does in the current application context by reading its title or understanding its icon. This is the information you need to make available to VoiceOver users in the label attribute.
>
> If you provide a custom control or view, or if you display a custom icon in a standard control or view, you need to provide a label that:
>
> - **Very briefly describes the element**. Ideally, the label consists of a single word, such as Add, Play, Delete, Search, Favorites, or Volume.
>     Strive to design your application so that a single word identifies an element and makes its usage obvious in the current context. Sometimes, however, it might be necessary to use a brief phrase to properly identify an element. When this is the case, create a very short phrase, such as “Play music,” “Add name,” or “Add to event.”
> - **Does not include the type of the control or view**. The type information is contained in the traits attribute of the element and should never be repeated in the label.
>     For example, if you include the control type in the label of an Add button, VoiceOver users hear “Add button button” every time they access that control. This experience would quickly become annoying and might motivate users to stop using your application.
> - **Begins with a capitalized word**. This helps VoiceOver read the label with the appropriate inflection.
> - **Does not end with a period**. The label is not a sentence and therefore should not end with a period.
> - **Is localized**. Be sure to make your application available to as wide an audience as possible by localizing all strings, including accessibility attribute strings. In general, VoiceOver speaks in the language that the user specifies in International settings.

Each tappable view should provide its own `accessibilityLabel`. If a user can tap on the header and the user can tap on the section below the header, then tapping on the header should just read the header and tapping on the section below the header should just read the section below the header.

Comment: Okay, fair enough - and I suppose that section is clearly saying that accessibility should be on an element-by-element basis, not grouping elements together semantically. In other words - nothing here is saying "you should group multiple elements together as one accessibility element." Still, I wish I could find some guideline which explicitly says not to group multiple elements together, otherwise it's still just one opinion versus another.

Comment: @BrianKendig: in my view, besides the a11y info in the docs, the best guideline for a11y with VoiceOver is YOU. Just switch on the 'curtain screen' feature on your device: you will find out that empathy and common sense are the basic principles to be added to your technical knowledge. All that will quickly improve the quality of your apps, for sure.  ;o)

Answer (score 2):

When you think about accessibility, you should be approaching it from the perspective of your end user. For example, if you have a heading entitled `Hospital Name:` with a subheading reading `Massachusetts General Hospital`, it would be a good idea to read the two together because they provide context for one another. If, on the other hand, you have a header entitled `Hospitals:` and then you have a long list of hospitals below, it would likely be better to allow the user to scroll through all of the hospitals at his/her own pace.

With larger blocks of text such as a paragraph on a UILabel or UITextView, the amount you read again depends on the context. If it is a description of something that should be read as a solid block without interruptions so the user can understand the content, then it is completely fine to set it as a single Voice Over block. If, however, there should be strategic pauses to allow the user to decide if he or she wants to hear more (e.g. End User License Agreement, paragraphs in an essay), then you should separate it into sections to allow the user to control the pace and select the location.

With larger blocks of text, I would recommend that you do not set the accessibilityLabel to the contents but rather the accessibilityValue. This will allow the user to hear a short description in the label of the object in the accessibility focus prior to deciding if he/she wants to hear more. Again, this gives the user context prior to continuing.

Answer (score 2):

You're developing a native app and not an html webapp?  In the latter case, the user can swipe left/right to navigate to the next element in the DOM and only the text that is associated with that DOM element is read.  However, the text associated with the DOM element can be "enhanced" by associating additional text with the DOM element (`aria-label`, `aria-labelledby`, `aria-describedby`, `class="sr-only"`, etc), if it's deemed necessary to help a VoiceOver user understand the context.  For example, a "register now" button or "read more" link might need additional information so that the purpose of the button/link is clear.  (Register for what now?  Read more about what?)

The same principle can be applied to native apps too, which sounds like what you're asking about.  If your app has a heading (ala `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc, but however it's defined in objectivec), then those shouldn't need additional text associated with them.  The heading should be worded so that it's context should be sufficient.  The paragraph following the heading can be navigated to by the user swiping right.  They'll know the paragraph is "under" the heading because it's the next element they swiped to.

Same if the user taps on the paragraph.  The heading associated with the paragraph does not need to be read.  The user can swipe left to get to it, or they can use the rotor set on "headings" to swipe up/down to get to the prev/next heading.

So the general guideline is to try to provide all the context that is needed in the text of the object itself, if possible.  But you also have to balance that with succinctness.  If the text needs additional context, then it sounds like you should use `accessibilityLabel`.  Is there another attribute that provides additional information such as accessibilityDescription?  (I just made that attribute name up.  Not sure if it exists.)

Comment: Yes, this is a native app. Your opinion is valid and I agree with you, but it's just an opinion and it's being countered by people on my team whose opinion is that the heading associated with the paragraph needs to be read. I'm looking for published accessibility guidelines that offer some precedent here.

Comment: I suppose it's opinion but it's based on over a decade in the field and working with visually impaired users.  The official guidelines for accessibility are WCAG (https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) but they will not tell you specifically about your situation.  That determination is made by years of experience, which I hope the people that are opposing your view have (but I don't agree with their evaluation).  What is their published guidelines for making their assessment?  Each element in the app should have their own text and not read the text of their neighbor.